# rsync Connection getting failed to remote server

Tags: rsync, windows-server-2019

I've configured a rsync server on a Windows Server 2019 (Server Name - ServerX).
rsync is working fine within the ServerX.
But none of my local machines are connected to ServerX via rsync.
rsync is getting failed between my local machine and ServerX.
I'm using a host entry with a url to connect to the ServerX.

protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(600) [sender=3.2.3]

I saw some solutions to do with bashrc file. It was not successful in my case.
Your expertise guidance is highly apprecialted.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly complaining about protocol versions; sometimes newer `rsync` releases introduce protocol differences, which are incompatible with older releases.

You can run `rsync --version` on both sides (ServerX and client) for comparison -- look for the `protocol version XX` part. Your client is most likely running version 3.2.3 which is protocol version 31. I suspect the server is running an older one.

To make your client talk to an older server use the command line parameter:

```
--protocol=NUM           force an older protocol version to be used
```

where NUM would be replaced e.g. by `26`.